# Asymptote to $\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I have seen elsewhere that:

$$y=\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

has a horizontal asymptote of $y=0$, as it approaches that line as $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$.

Now, why does it not have an asymptote of $x=0$ or $y=1$, as the curve tends towards but never touches these lines? (Which satisfies the definition given by [wolfram alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Asymptote.html))

Comment: The line $x=0$ is a vertical line, not a horizontal line. Additionally, the line $y=0$ (which I think you mean?) is not an asymptote, because $y$ has the value of $0$ for many values of $x$.

Comment: the ''official'' asymptote is $y=0$.

Comment: Ahaha thanks - I mixed up the $x$s and $y$s in my head. Fixed that in the edit.

Comment: $y=0$ is an asymptote, in that the entire curve is within a small neighborhood of this line once you restrict to large enough $x$. $y=1$ is not, because the curve is always "far away" from $y=1$ once $|x| \geq 2$. Note that there is a common misconception that a curve will not touch its asymptotes; maybe this is because of the important special case of rational functions with distinct linear factors.

Comment: You could start reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote). The value of the asymptote has to be the limit of the function. $\sin(x)/x\rightarrow 0\neq 1$.

Comment: @Ian, but y tends to 1 as x tends to 0?

Comment: Limits at finite points are not what asymptotes are about. If it were then a typical continuous function would have a whole continuum of asymptotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make our definition of an asymptote more clear.

An vertical asymptote for $x=a$ occurs if $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\pm\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=\pm\infty$.  The limit from the left does not have to equal the limit on the right, in fact there is an asymptote as long as one side goes to $\pm\infty$.  Take the asymptote of $f(x)=\ln(x)$ for example.

A horizontal asymptote for $y=b$ occurs if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=b$ or if $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=b$, where $b$ is finite.

We can also have a curved asymptote.  Say $f(x)$ is asymptotic to $g(x)$, then $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0$.  The two functions must both get really close to each other as $x$ becomes arbitrarily large.

So to answer your questions, $y=0$ is an asymptote but $x=0$ and $y=1$ are not.

Comment: I would make slightly different definitions.  I would allow a vertical asymptote where just one side goes to $\pm \infty$. And a horizontal asymptote in just one of the two directions $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.  For example, $e^{-x}$ has $y=0$ as an asymptote.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The line $y=1$ is an ordinary tangent, not an asymptote. An asymptote is a tangent *at infinity*.

[image]

In red the tangent, in green the asymptote.

---

Maybe clearer with another function.

[image]